# Should you try not to level up?

Tags: backyard-monsters

In backyard monsters, it seems like your neighbors are always around the same levels as you. While you can't really play and not earn EXP, you can try to limit which EXP you get. For example, attacking neighbors will give you resources, and attacking the town hall gives you no resources but a ton of EXP. (However, if you don't destroy the town hall, technically you have lost the battle).

Should you try not to gain EXP in order to keep yourself surrounded with low-level neighbors? Is this a good strategy?

Comment: The game tag for this question was lost to the tag grue; please confirm I got it right :)

Comment: Yes, you got it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm level 45, and I would say go for everything you can get. The best strategy is to level as fast as possible, keep your workers working on upgrading resource buildings and farm kozus as much as possible. If you have a strong resource income to draw on, then you'll basically be unstoppable. A high level doesn't mean anything except to intimidate lesser skilled players into not attacking you.